# Show that $1^{5}+2^{5}+ \dots + 100^{5}$ is divisible by $10100$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that $1^{5}+2^{5}+ \dots + 100^{5}$ is divisible by $10100$.

---

the given expression can be rephrased like this: $(1^{5}+100^{5})+(2^{5}+99^{5})+ \dots + (50^{5}+51^{5})$. Each of these pairs would be divisible by $101$ and there are $50$ such pairs so the expression is divisible by $101,50$, now we need to prove that it's divisible by $2$ to complete the first part of the question. Notice there are $50$ odd and $50$ even numbers in the expression, so those $50$ even numbers are also divisible by $2$. Now every of those odd numbers raised to the power $5$ would give $ 1 (\bmod 2)$ and there are $50$ such terms, so when added, they will be $50 (\bmod 2)$ which is $0 (\bmod 2)$ and hence they will be divisible by $2$. Is this solution correct? My doubt about this solution is that I proved the expression to be divisible by $2$ but that $2$ might just be the part of $50$ that I showed earlier, which will just mean I have shown that the above expression is divisible by $101$ times $50$ that is $5050$ and not $10100$.

Comment: Why is each pair divisible by $101$?

Comment: @FShrike... In $a^5+(101-a)^5$ expand with binomial theorem.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks, I've never seen that trick before

Comment: @FShrike, see that $a^5+b^5=(a+b)(a^4-a^3b+a^2b^2-ab^3+b^4)$.

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure as to how you proved that the sum is divisible by 50,cause each of the 50 sums are not equal so your solution doesn't hold unless you have done some modular arithmetic which you have not shown here(or I am missing some trivial fact).Moreover,if a number is divisible by 50 then it is already an even number,to show that it is divisible by 100 you have to show that the number is divisible by 4 otherwise you can't conclude divisibility by 100.

**Here is my Solution**

As you did we divide the total sum into parts like $(1^5+100^5)+(2^5+99^5)+.........+(50^5+51^5)$.
This shows divisibility by 101.As for divisibility by 100 consider the sum as $(1^5+99^5)+(2^5+98^5)+........+(49^5+51^5)+50^5+100^5$.
Each of the sum enclosed by the brackets is divisible by 100.Also it is trivial that $100\mid 50^5+100^5 $.So 100 also divide the given sum.And as 100 ans 101 are co-prime their product also divide the given sum

Comment: Nice answer! Small typo: One of your brackets has $(2^3+98^3)$ where the powers should be $5$.